# Jogo da Forca em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jogos

Estou fazendo um jogo da forca em Python. A cada *loop* o programa pergunta a letra ou a palavra:

```
#Jogo
perguntarNovamente = True
game_on = True
while game_on:
    palavra_secreta = palavra()
    senha_list = [l for l in palavra_secreta]
    chances = 6
    tentativas = []
    #Esconder palavra
    for i in range(101):
        print()
    print (senha_list) #APENAS PARA TESTE
    #Começo do jogo
    while perguntarNovamente:
        print("A palavra:","_ "*len(senha_list))
        erros = 0
        desenho(erros)
        an = input("Digite uma letra(ou a palavra): ")
        if an == palavra_secreta:
            print("Parabéns você acertou!!")
            break
        elif an not in(senha_list):
            if an in(tentativas):
                print("Você já tentou essa letra!")
                continue
            else:
                print("Não há essa letra na palavra!")
                tentativas.append(an)
                erros +=1
                continue
        else:
            print("Você acertou uma letra!")
            tentativas.append(an)
            continue
    break
```

A cada vez que o jogador bota uma letra errada o variável `erros` aumenta em 1, então uso ela como parâmetro para chamar a função `desenho` que desenha a forca e o boneco de acordo com o número de erros:

```
def desenho(erros):
if erros == 0:
    print()
    print("|----- ")
    print("|    | ")
    print("|      ")
    print("|      ")
    print("|      ")
    print("|      ")
    print("_      ")
    print()
 #Não botei todos!! e está indentado!
 elif erros == 6:
    print()
    print("|----- ")
    print("|    | ")
    print("|    O ")
    print("|   /|\\ ")
    print("|    | ")
    print("|   / \\ ")
    print("_      ")
    print()
```

Porém com o aumento da variável `erros` o desenho não muda de acordo! Como posso resolver?

Link do código: https://repl.it/Dbef/0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dentro do looping `while perguntarNovamente:`, você está inicializando a variável `erros = 0`, portanto, toda vez que o looping é executado, essa variável volta a ter o valor zero.

Uma solução possível é inicializar `erros` antes de entrar no looping:

```
#Começo do jogo
erros = 0 # AQUI => inicializa a variável erros fora do looping principal
while perguntarNovamente:
    print("A palavra:","_ "*len(senha_list))
    desenho(erros)
    ...
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @ViniciusBarbosa: De nada!! :)

Answer (score -2):

```
import os
import getpass
import netrc
import random

def Clear():
    os.system('cls')
    print("\n" *10)

def Desintegrar(string):
    CPalavra = list()
    for c in string:
        CPalavra.append(c.upper())
    print(CPalavra)

Palavra = ""
Copia = ""
Acertos = 0
Tentat = 6
LErros = 0
Id = tam = 0
Acerto = False
Letras = ""
Letra = ""

print("\033[32m ===== JOGO DA FORCA =====\033[m")
try:
    Palavra = str(input("\033[34mDigite uma Palavra para Ocultar: \033[m")).upper()
    while Palavra.isnumeric():
        print("\033[31m > Palavra Inválida. Tente Novamente...\033[m")
        Palavra = str(input("\033[32mDigite uma Palavra para Ocultar: \033[m")).upper()
except ValueError:
    print("\033[31m > Valor Inválido.\033[m")

tam = len(Palavra)
Clear()

print("\033[32mPalavra ocultada com Sucesso!\033[m")
PalavraCóp = list()
for ele in Palavra:
    PalavraCóp.append(ele.replace(ele, '_'))

while Acertos < tam or Tentat < 6:
    print("\n\033[33mPalavra é: ", end='')
    for item in PalavraCóp:
        print(f"{item}", end=' ')
    print("\033[m")

    try:
        Letra = str(input("\n\033[34m> Digite uma Letra: \033[m")).upper()[0]
        Letras += Letra
        while Letra.isnumeric():
            print("\033[31m> Letra Inválida. Tente Novamente...\033[m")
            Letra = str(input("\n\033[34m> Digite uma Letra: \033[m")).upper()[0]
            Letras += Letra
    except ValueError():
        print("\033[31m > Valor Inválido.\033[m")

    for c, value in enumerate(Palavra):
        if value == Letra:
            print(f"\033[32m> Letra [{Letra}] encontrada com sucesso.\033[m")
            PalavraCóp[c] = Letra
            Acerto = True
            Acertos += 1

    if Acertos == tam:
        print(f"\033[92m=============== FIM ================\n"
              f"=========== Você Venceu. =========== \033[m")
        break

    if Acerto == False:
        LErros += 1
        Tentat-=1
        print(f"\033[31m > Letra [{Letra}] não encontrada. Tente Novamente...\033[m")
        print("\033[33m > Tentativas restantes: [{}].\033[m".format(Tentat))

    if Tentat == 0:
        print("\n\033[33m ========= FIM =========="
              "\n> As tentativas acabaram.\n\033[m")
        break
    Acerto = False

print(f"\033[96m => Palavra encontrada: {PalavraCóp}")
print(f" => Letras Digitadas: [{Letras}]")
print(f" => Total de Letras Digitadas: [{len(Letras)}]")
print(f" => Total de Tentativas com sucesso: [{tam}]")
print(f" => Total de Tentativas Erradas: [{LErros}]\033[m")
print("\033[92m====================================\033[m")
```

Comment: O que faz isso? Veja [answer] e faça o nosso [tour].